# Capedwarf: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,1]

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly, capedwarf

I'm trying to run my application in debug mode as described in [Debuggin an application in Wildfly with Eclipse](http://www.techbyapro.com/debugging-an-application-in-wildfly-with-eclipse.html)and [JBoss Tools - Debugging an Externally launched WildFly](http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2015-03-17-debugging-an-externally-launched-wildfly.html) but, when I execute *./standalone.sh --debug --server-config=standalone.xml* command, I get this error:

> user@user:~/wildfly-8.1.0.CR1/bin$ ./standalone.sh --debug --server-config=standalone-capedwaf-modules.xml
>
> > =========================================================================
>
> ```
> JBoss Bootstrap Environment
>
> JBOSS_HOME: /home/giacomo/wildfly-8.1.0.CR1
>
> JAVA: java
>
> JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
> ```
>
> =========================================================================
>       Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787 11:11:47,210 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
>   11:11:47,415 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version
>   1.2.2.Final 11:11:47,490 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015899: JBoss Capedwarf 2.0.1.Final (WildFly 8.1.0.CR1) starting
>   11:11:47,812 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot:
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException:
>   JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration   at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:112)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.CR1.jar:8.1.0.CR1]   at
>   org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:331)
>   [wildfly-server-8.1.0.CR1.jar:8.1.0.CR1]   at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:256)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.CR1.jar:8.1.0.CR1]   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80] Caused by:
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,1]
>   Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:2.2}server'   at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:104)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.CR1.jar:8.1.0.CR1]   ... 3 more
>       11:11:47,814 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner;
>   exiting. See previous messages for details.

I understan that the error is in my standalone.xml at [row,col]:[3,1] but I don't know what is wrong.
Below my .xml:

> ```
> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
>
> <server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.1">
>
> <extensions>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.capedwarf"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.messaging"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
>     <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
>     <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
>     <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
> </extensions>
>
>
>
>
>
> <management>
>     <security-realms>
>         <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
>             <authentication>
>                 <local default-user="$local"/>
>                 <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
>             </authentication>
>             <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
>                 <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
>             </authorization>
>         </security-realm>
>         <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
>             <authentication>
>                 <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*"/>
>                 <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
>             </authentication>
>             <authorization>
>                 <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
>             </authorization>
>         </security-realm>
>     </security-realms>
>     <management-interfaces>
>         <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
>             <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
>         </native-interface>
>         <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
>             <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
>         </http-interface>
>     </management-interfaces>
> </management>
>
>
>
> <profile>
>     <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:capedwarf:1.0"/>
>     <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
>         <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
>             <level name="INFO"/>
>             <formatter>
>                 <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
>             </formatter>
>         </console-handler>
>         <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
>             <formatter>
>                 <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
>             </formatter>
>             <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
>             <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
>             <append value="true"/>
>         </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
>         <logger category="com.arjuna">
>             <level name="WARN"/>
>         </logger>
>         <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
>             <level name="WARN"/>
>         </logger>
>         <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
>             <level name="DEBUG"/>
>         </logger>
>         <logger category="sun.rmi">
>             <level name="WARN"/>
>         </logger>
>         <logger category="jacorb">
>             <level name="WARN"/>
>         </logger>
>         <logger category="jacorb.config">
>             <level name="ERROR"/>
>         </logger>
>         <root-logger>
>             <level name="INFO"/>
>             <handlers>
>                 <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
>                 <handler name="FILE"/>
>             </handlers>
>         </root-logger>
>     </subsystem>
>     <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
>         <datasources>
>             <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS"
> ```
>
> enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
>                       jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
>                       h2
>                       
>                           sa
>                           sa
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                       
>                           org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
>                       
>                   
>               
>           
>           
>               
>           
>           
>               false
>               true

Could you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

there is a typo in your command line:

```
./standalone.sh --debug --server-config=standalone-capedwaf-modules.xml
```

`capedwaf` should be `capedwarf`

Answer (score 1):

How are you using / building the CapeDwarf extension?

As I see you're using upstream master -- as (unfortunately) we never released 2.0.1.Final ... :-(

Since capedwarf-jboss-as is using WF 8.2.1.Final: https://github.com/capedwarf/capedwarf-jboss-as/blob/master/pom.xml#L57

I suggest you use CapeDwarf 2.0.0.Final from official download.

And if you still have some issues, let me know, and I'll try to do new release with the fixes. ;-)

Comment: Is `2.0.0.Final` still recommended for use in a production environment?